# Why do I get an error saying variable radius may not be initialized?

Tags: java

The purpose is to create a constructor that takes two variables and makes sure they are in the correct range (>0). Also to initialize the iceCreamHeight to 0.

```
public class Cone {
    private final double radius;    // doesn't change after Cone is constructed 
    private final double height; // doesn't change after Cone is constructed
    private double iceCreamHeight;  
    public Cone(double radius, double height){
        iceCreamHeight = 0; 
        double r = radius; 
        double h = height;
        if(r <=0 || h <=0 || iceCreamHeight <= 0){
            r =1;
            h=1;
            System.out.println("ERROR Cone");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

No where in this program do you attempt to change the values of `radius` or `height`. Use the `this` keyword to reference the variables:

```
public class Cone {
    private final double radius;
    private final double height;
    private double iceCreamHeight;  
    public Cone(double radius, double height){
        this.iceCreamHeight = 0; 
        this.radius = radius; //Uses 'this'
        this.height = height;
        if(this.radius <= 0 || this.height <= 0 || this.iceCreamHeight <= 0){
            this.radius = 1;
            this.height= 1;
            System.out.println("ERROR Cone");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `radius` and `height` can still be `final`, and doing so might be desirable in order ensure that nothing _outside_ the constructor can change them.

Comment: `final` fields are a very good thing.  There are better ways to resolve this problem than removing something beneficial.

Comment: @VGR when I wrote this answer, I did not know that final fields could be set in an object's constructor. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

The constructor's parameters are always local variables; in this case, they happen to have the same name as the instance variables, but the parameters and the instance variables aren't the same.  You have to have an explicit assignment statement to set the local variables; either change the parameter names to be something different (for instance, just use `r` and `h` as the parameter names, something like

```
public Cone(double r, double h) {
    // check the parameters here
    // note that you can assign new values to r and h; there's
    // no reason to declare separate variables to hold the same value
    radius = r;
    height = h;
}
```

, or use `this.radius` and `this.height` to access the instance variables, like

```
public Cone(double radius, double height) {
    // check the parameters here
    this.radius = radius;
    this.height = height;
}
```